# Unlikely vs Not likely

Tags: word-usage, difference, phrase-usage

Is there a difference between "unlikely" and "not likely"? Or can they both be used interchangeably? And in what contexts can they be used in?

E.g.

> It is not likely that I will get full marks for this test

> It is unlikely that I will get full marks for this test

Is there a difference between these two sentences for example?

Comment: It would help if you gave some examples of how you might like to use these words, otherwise the answer to this (and almost all other "are they interchangeable" questions) is "Sometimes".  Giving an example or two can help me understand the specific problem that you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many contexts, they are the same or similar in meaning:

> It is not likely that the Prime Minister will resign.

> It is unlikely that the Prime Minister will resign

Similarly in your example, the meanings are very similar.

With emphasis you could vary the meaning:

> It's not *likely* that the PM will resign, but it is quite possible! # ie probability is about 20%-50%

> It's *unlikely* that the PM will resign, but nothing is impossible.  # ie probability 1%-10%

As an interjection, "Not likely!" is the idiom and means "I certainly won't (do something) It's informal (and British?)

> Are you going home?
>
> Not likely! I'm just getting started.